# MATLAB Prevent Function return while figure open

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-gui

I have built a GUI programatically (not in GUIDE) that accepts a number of inputs from the user. It's called by another script (in another .m file). The GUI returns 3 variables.

```
[X Y Z] = MyGUIfunction(Arg1);
```

**My problem is that execution of the calling script seems to continue BEFORE MyGUIfunction completes (and returns variables).**

MATLAB returns error message:

```
Output argument "X" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "etcetc\MyGUIfunction"
```

This error message is true, X Y and Z are not set until the user has finished input and closed the figure.

How can I prevent the calling script from continuing before X Y and Z have been determined? I've had a go with uiwait() but couldn't get the required behaviour.

edit 2016-06-27

This Function:

```
function TempDelete_2()

%Would actually like to call this and WAIT for arguments to be returned
[rX rY rZ] = TempDelete_1();
%Matlab throws error here because rX, rY and rZ have NOT been set

disp(rX)
disp(rY)
disp(rZ)
end
```

Calls this function:

```
function [X Y Z] = TempDelete_1()


fH = 550;
fW = 900;
fL = 280;
fB = 280;

h_baseFig = figure('menubar','none','Position',[fL , fB, fW, fH],'name','Create Init','NumberTitle','off','ResizeFcn',@InitFigCB_SizeChangedFcn);

%Ok Button
f_okBut = uicontrol(h_baseFig,'style','pushbutton','position',[fW-90 10 80 35],'string','OK','Callback',@CB_OKdone);

    function CB_OKdone(~,~,~)

        X=1;
        Y=2;
        Z=3;
        close(h_baseFig);
        return
    end

end
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Some code would be helpful...